# What is happening when starting a Spark application on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, kubernetes, hadoop-yarn

I read this: [Running Spark on Kubernetes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#submitting-applications-to-kubernetes).
I want to know more details about the interaction between Kubernetes Controller/Scheduler and Spark runtime when launching a Spark job on K8s.
Specially, assuming we launch an Spark app by :

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port> \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-pi \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--..............
```

My question is: the K8s may not be able to allocate 5 executors (or called containers/pods) immediately due to unavailability of cluster resources at the moment the Spark app is launched. Which way does Spark app take? (1) Spark starts running tasks as soon as possible when there is at least one executor is allocated. (2) Spark won't launch any tasks until all of the 5 executors have been allocated.

If you know Hadoop YARN, it would be great if you could also answer the question in the scenario of running Spark app on Hadoop YARN(DynamicAllocation Disabled) and point out the difference.

Comment: The last time I looked, it waited until all executor pods were ready before continuing. But that was about a year ago so I don't want to put this as an answer, there is a reasonable chance the behavior has improved since then.

Comment: @coderanger Thanks! Do you mean K8s or YARN?

Comment: Kubernetes. The driver can always create the executor pod objects, but those pods might sit there and not be ready if there is nowhere for them to run.

Comment: I've just tried with Spark `2.4.0` and the tasks were started as soon as there were  "`spark.executor.instances`" of executors. I also tried to kill one executor during the job and the driver was able to survive this... well it created another whole set of new executors. Btw. if you want to create a spark cluster in advance and connect to it, consider using my operator https://github.com/radanalyticsio/spark-operator It has support for both, `spark-on-k8s` dynamic clusters and also for long running ones.

Comment: @JiriKremser thanks!